# Is there an easy way in python to find the bpy.data.images that are used in a node?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, image

I know a couple of ways to get images in the node_tree, the simplest is:

```
image_list=[]
for n in bpy.data.materials['My Mat'].node_tree.nodes:
    if n.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
        if n.image:
            if n.image not in image_list:
                image_list.append(n.image)
```

Clearly, it is the fastest way if group type nodes are not used. Alternatively you can build a function that iterates over groups, subgroups etc. It's not a problem. technically I can get to all the images in any sub-group

So basically I can currently get to all the data images. but I was wondering, is there a python api that allows you to see directly which images bpy.data.images are related to bpy.data.materials['My Mat'] ?

**Note:**
The main purpose is, to keep track in real time in the panel, of how many images there are in that node tree.
So that method (which I proposed in the example) is wasteful of resources if the materials are very complex. It would run too many times when the cursor is touched on the panel.

Comment: Since all materials are node based, I guess there is no other way to determine whether an image is in use, also I can not find anything related in the docs.

Comment: So... if the answer is not in Python code... the answer is just "no"?

Comment: Not sure it will be quicker.  Could play around with users. _ie_ make a list of all users `[im.users for im in D.images]` copy a material, recreate list. Any that have incremented  user count are in use by the material. Then remove dupe.  Similarly with materials using  node groups using images.

Comment: @batFINGER but `im.users` is just user count I think and is a simple integer. are there any other ways to get users?

Comment: @NoobCat. A direct api does not exist for that. And even if it exists, that won't solve what you say (wasteful when used in draw). So could you provide more informaton about the context of your question? (the idea may be to avoid doing it in draw)

Comment: @lemon Keep track of how many images are in use in a Material (Or node_tree) in real time, printed on the UI, without having to press buttons or the like. Obviously it is very expensive not having a direct API. I can't even count the D. images, because even if an image is deleted from the node tree, it will always remain in memory, because it could have User, or simply be in Orphan Data. So I can't even do something like if len (D.image)! = Len (my_prop.my_last_data_images_list) where, my_prop, could be a scene property, which is only updated when the 2 lists are different

Comment: @NoobCat if you could provide a test case for evaluation?

Comment: @lemon I don't have any tests at the moment, it doesn't make any sense, mine is just a hypothesis, but at the moment it lacks any foundation. It was just a food for thought.

Comment: @lemon both an excellent answer, and source of a test file https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161371/15543  Are you too young to be lucky enough to program  (ie plug the wires into) analogue computers too?  (as with other recursion excursions in python, could be quicker with iterative approach)

Comment: @batFINGER, thanks. Tested it on 1k times on 'Logic Node Libary' for around 0.8s here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Recurse the tree.**

In question code, the major rate determining step will be checking the list for dupe to append, often quicker to add them all and use a set if only unique members are of interest.

Suggest can use list comprehension, or recursively walk the tree.

Here is an example, pass a node tree to a method and walk its nodes, if it has an image property yield it, if it has a node tree yield from it.

*Personally I like the simplicity of yield syntax usage for traversing a tree, and the low memory hogging nature of generators, however they need a little tweaking to optimize for speed, see below*

```
import bpy

def images_in_tree(node_tree):
    for node in node_tree.nodes:
        if hasattr(node, "image"):
            yield node.image
        if hasattr(node, "node_tree"):
            yield from images_in_tree(node.node_tree)
        
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.use_nodes:
        print(set(filter(None, images_in_tree(mat.node_tree))))
```

*Note could yield above `getattr(node, "image", None)` to avoid testing and filter out the Nones, however it may be a better idea to yield the node_tree, and the node.  The ID data of the node_tree `node_tree.id_data` will be a material or a node group.*

**Just the number of unique images in tree.**

In answer to

> Keep track of how many images are in use in a Material (Or node_tree)
> in real time, printed on the UI, without having to press buttons or
> the like

Instead of yielding the images returns only a count.

Used a boolean default dictionary to tag items. *Any item is given the default value false*

In response to

> fyi, you can't use `tag` here. Or any optimization like caching.

Have tagged both the nodegroups and images with one dict to  make the method directly usable in a draw method, instead of using say a getter of a material property,

```
bpy.types.Material.image_users = IntProperty(get=num_images)
```

*In which case could lay it out with*

```
layout.prop(mat, "image_users")
```

and using the `collection.tag(False)` would be Ok in this context, and removes the need for the default dictionary.

As noted yielding and recursion can be slow in python, however using [`functools.lru_cache`](https://realpython.com/lru-cache-python/) seriously fixes this see similar gain here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199075/15543 as well as other optimizations used. *See lru_cache link re expiring or clearing cache on some interval*

Basically it is caching the result of a call to memory.

```
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(16) # play with this
def num_images(mat):
    tag = defaultdict(bool)
    
    def unique(node):
        img = getattr(node, "image", None) 
        if tag[img]:
            return False
        tag[img] = True
        return img is not None

     
    def images_in_tree(node_trees):
        for node_tree in node_trees:
            if tag[node_tree]:
                continue
            tag[node_tree] = True
            yield sum(unique(n) for n in node_tree.nodes)
            yield from images_in_tree((n.node_tree  for n in node_tree.nodes if hasattr(n, "node_tree")))
    return sum(images_in_tree((mat.node_tree,)))

# make an int material property 
bpy.types.Material.image_users = bpy.props.IntProperty(get=num_images.__wrapped__)
# tack a draw method to text editor footer to test
from random import random
def draw(self, context):
    mat = context.object.active_material
    if mat:
        self.layout.prop(mat, "image_users")
        if random() <= 0.5:
            num_images.cache_clear()
        self.layout.label(text=f"{num_images(mat)}")
        
bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.prepend(draw)
```

The material property uses an uncached version of the method above, `num_images.__wrapped__` the label uses the cached method.  The cache is cleared each time a random is below a threshold. The expectation above is that it is only calculated approximately every 2nd time.

Other methods to consider would be using a counter on the UI class, clearing in a `draw, poll or __init__` method of classes in different regions, a draw call back.. (Or as mentioned prior expire the cache) or simply not use it at all.

[image]
*Extra image tacked into test file, showing 8 images in material, removed shows 7, undo back to 8*

Comment: It looks good, I'll have to test it! Let's see how it behaves with 800+ Nodes. (I'm not kidding XD)

Comment: Cool. Even it slows things down, might be useful to check whether an image node is connected at all.

Comment: Would be tricky. Know I often leave unconnected "thinking about using" nodes littered around.  Testing for nodes with  valid paths to output could be something to look at.

Comment: If you `group.tag` before the loop it won't count images per node tree.

Comment: fyi, you can't use `tag` here. Or any optimization like caching.

Answer (score 8):

So... it seems quite confirmed that there is no api to do that. And even if this api exist it would be called as often in the context.

You can either recurse into, or iterate over, subnodes that are groups.

But in both case there is no need to go through the same groups several times (as we may find the same images and their `users` property won't change for that).

To collect the images without duplicates or to test if a group is already parsed, we can use a `set()`.

**Recursive way**

```
def search_images_recursive4(material):
    node_trees = set()
    if material.use_nodes:
        def search_trees(trees):
            for tree in trees:
                if not tree in node_trees:
                    node_trees.add(tree)
                    search_trees((n.node_tree for n in tree.nodes if hasattr(n, "node_tree")))
        search_trees((material.node_tree,))
        
    return set(n.image for t in node_trees for n in t.nodes if hasattr(n,"image") and n.image)
```

**Iterative way**

```
def search_images_iterative3(material):
    result = set()
    if material.use_nodes:
        encountered = set()
        trees = set((material.node_tree,))
        while trees:
            encountered.update(trees)
            result.update(n.image for t in trees for n in t.nodes if hasattr(n, "image"))
            trees = set(n.node_tree for t in trees for n in t.nodes if hasattr(n, "node_tree")).difference(encountered)
            
    return result
```

---

**Test case**: the file from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161370/is-there-a-way-to-use-logic-operators-in-blender-shader-nodes/161371#161371).

The test is a 1000 times loop call each function over all the materials of the file.

Run it 10  times and took the average.

```
import time

n = 1000
start = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    for mat in [m for m in bpy.data.materials if m.use_nodes]:
        pass #call the function to test here instead of pass
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Results:

New @batFINGER solution `num_images`: 4.4 seconds.

`search_images_recursive4`: 3.17 seconds

`search_images_iterative3`: 3.26 seconds

---

**Note**

What I've finally discovered (and learned) is using

```
hasattr(n, "node_tree")
```

is the key point as it is much faster than

```
n.type == 'GROUP'
```

Comment: For your information, @batFINGER, with tags, quite similar in runtime.

Comment: would still avoid `if x in y` if possible.

Comment: in counterpart, `yield` is just very slow...  @batFINGER

Comment: Here it is really difficult, to assign the Bounty, guys, I ask you, in your opinion which of the 2 answers is the best. Really hard for me to decide.

Comment: Well, NoobCat, you want something fast. As I said above, `yield` is slow (around 7x slower in my test cases)... but @batFINGER may also answer you about that. I've tested several ways and `search_images_recursive2`above is the best one I've found.

Comment: And additionally, using `tag`has a counterpart: looping for tagging, which is slow also, so that it brings no better performance.

Comment: @NoobCat. I think the best way for you to choose is to test and compare. This is your question and so your responsability in some way : )

Comment: Can't see any DV's, you can click on the number to verify. Btw: Nice answer!

Comment: @brockmann, thanks... it has been retracted, it seems.