# Enumerating Images used by BSDF Node Tree

Tags: python, materials, scripting, export

I'm trying to enumerate and export all images used by all materials in a given .blend project and associating them with named slots / channels used by BSDFs.

My problem is determining which images are assigned to which element in the material's node tree. The toolchain expects things to be named a certain way (ie. "diffuse" instead of "Base Color") and I don't want to always have to remember to change the texture's name every time for every texture. Here's what I've got finding images in Python.

```
real_texture_list = []
test_texture_list = []

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    for s in obj.material_slots:
        if s.material and s.material.use_nodes:
            for n in s.material.node_tree.nodes:
                if n.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                    if n.image.type == 'UV_TEST':
                        test_texture_list += [n.image]
                    elif n.image.type == 'IMAGE':
                        real_texture_list += [n.image]
                elif n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                   print(n.inputs["Base Color"]) # want the "Base Color" image object so I can name it something else on export
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [python, find images that are used in a node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186192/is-there-an-easy-way-in-python-to-find-the-bpy-data-images-that-are-used-in-a-no/204950#204950)

Comment: Not quite sure either. It didn't fully answer my question. I need a list of pairs of (channel, image) per material, where the channel is 'Base Color', 'Normal', etc. The channel list is defined per BSDF type.