# How to get a high peformance `not operator` in shader nodes?

Tags: mathematics, shader-nodes

In [Is there a way to use logic operators in Blender Shader nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161370/is-there-a-way-to-use-logic-operators-in-blender-shader-nodes) the answer provides a `not` operator however it uses a *nand* operator to achieve this which is too computationally expensive for my needs.

To give a little more information I need a *not* operator which will be used a few hundred times in my node tree, therefore it should be as computationally cheap as possible.

I know that the *invert* node does something like this but it inverts first, converts my float input into a color input, then inverts on all three channels and then converts back. Not exactly computationally cheap.

Is there a better way than this (preferably a single node solution)?

Comment: Math node 1-value?

Comment: I also thought of that but does that work out with floating point imprecision?

Comment: Whole numbers are precise

Comment: Ahh, ok thanks!